# A tool showing a breakdown of completion times and source machine names for each and every mapper and reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I know job tasks page (in the JobTracker UI) is already showing start time and end time of every tasks in mapper and reducer but I would like to see something more like source machine names, number of spills and so on. I guess I can try to write such a tool using JobTracker class? But before embarking on that, I would like to see if there is such a tool already.

Comment: Maybe look into Vaidya, it might provide the functionality that you are looking for - http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/vaidya.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `hadoop job -history all output-dir` command give you enough information to parse / process?

- http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/cluster_setup.html - Search for the above command